# What does the "value" attribute in <set> element of spring web flow contain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflow

I am a beginner to Spring Web Flow. I came across this  tag in flow xml files. One such example is

```
<on-start>
    <set name="flowScope.products" value="cartService.products"/>
    <set name="flowScope.shippingOptions"value="cartService.shippingOptions"/>
    <set name="requestScope.productId" value="requestParameters.productId"/>
</on-start>
```

What does the value - `cartService.shippingOptions` mean? Is it referring any java field? or is it just a string? what does `value  = "requestParameters.productId"`
refer to ? On the whole, what are the possible values for a `<set>` tag?
I referred the documents, but not clear. Can anyone please help whether the value attribute of `<set>` tag contains a string or is it reference to a java field?

Please find the link for the whole code 
https://github.com/DanielMichalski/spring-web-flow/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/checkout.xml

Can anyone please answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requestParameters` is a special EL variable referring to the parameters in the http request. see [special variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/el.html#el-variables)

`value` is more generally an EL expression that can be evaluated. you can use any spring beans, inputs, variables, scopes, event etc.

see [this link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/el.html) for more details about EL